# What is the distribution of this function of a table of random coin-flip variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm working on a problem in the domain of cellular automatons and I have managed to get some results conditional on the asymptotic behavior of the following function of a table of $0$'s and $1$'s:

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we consider a triangular table
$$A:= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 &... & 0 & 0 \\ X_1^n & X_2^n &... & X_n^n \\ ...& ...&...\\X_1^2 & X_2^2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
where all $X$'s are from $\{0,1\}$.

Now we define a counting function:
$$\#_n(_{0}^{00}, A) = \#\{(i,j)|\begin{pmatrix} A(i,j) & A(i+1,j) \\ A(i,j+1) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\}$$
and more generally
$$\#_n(_{z}^{xy}, A) = \#\{(i,j)|\begin{pmatrix} A(i,j) & A(i+1,j) \\ A(i,j+1) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ z \end{pmatrix}\}$$

So for example
$$A:= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}\implies \begin{matrix} \#_n(_{0}^{00}, A) = 1\\
\#_n(_{1}^{00}, A) = 2\\
\#_n(_{0}^{01}, A) = 2\\
\#_n(_{1}^{01}, A) = 0\\
\#_n(_{0}^{10}, A) = 0\\
\#_n(_{1}^{10}, A) = 0\\
\#_n(_{0}^{11}, A) = 0\\
\#_n(_{1}^{11}, A) = 1\end{matrix}$$

Now the question is this:

For any choice of $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8)$ how many $A$'s are there that satisfy
$$\begin{matrix} \#_n(_{0}^{00}, A) = a_1\\
\#_n(_{1}^{00}, A) = a_2\\
\#_n(_{0}^{01}, A) = a_3\\
\#_n(_{1}^{01}, A) = a_4\\
\#_n(_{0}^{10}, A) = a_5\\
\#_n(_{1}^{10}, A) = a_6\\
\#_n(_{0}^{11}, A) = a_7\\
\#_n(_{1}^{11}, A) = a_8\end{matrix}$$

Or put in another way, if we say that $X$'s above are independent coin-flips what is the joint distribution of $\big{(}\#_n(_{0}^{00}, A),\#_n(_{1}^{00}, A),\#_n(_{0}^{01}, A),\#_n(_{1}^{01}, A),\#_n(_{0}^{10}, A),\#_n(_{1}^{10}, A),\#_n(_{0}^{11}, A),\#_n(_{1}^{11}, A)\big{)}$

If normalized by multiplying by $2^{-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$ that vector random variable approaches $(\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8})$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, but my situation is very delicate and the exact distribution is needed.

Now I'm not asking anyone to compute this - rather can anyone here notice a recurrence formula between these $\#$'s that would allow me to continue with the tedious part? I tried my best, but combinatorics isn't my strongest suit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify which entries of $A$ are required to be 0? Is it just the first and last row?

Comment: Yes, only those.
In fact, what I'm getting at is how much the distribution will change if we replace all 0's in the first row with 1's. Hopefully, for any a = (a_1,...,a_8), the difference of P(a) for those two cases is of order O(2^n) instead of O(2^n^2).

Comment: If you seek a recurrence relation, maybe considering when the size $n$ increase to $n+1$, then we inserting a new row of $X^{n+1}$ at the second row. By doing so the counts at the lower part will remain the same. The only change will be the upper part. It will seems need to remember the number of $1$s in each row (at least the second / third row) to work.

Comment: Is it true that the number of $A$ of size $n$ such that $\#_n(_0^{00}, A) = 0$, as a sequence of $n$, begins 1, 2, 7, 42, 431?

Comment: Ah, I missed that the bottom row has to be 0. Is it 1, 0, 1, 3, 20? Or perhaps you have some data somewhere to inspect? :)